# How do I write this url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I know that there has been question concerning url re-write but the once I have seen have not solved my problem.

I have to edit this question.

Forward slash is not working when I am re-writing a url. WHat do I do

Comment: Is the part you're struggling with converting the hyphen into a space? Can there be zero or multiple hyphens?

Comment: Forward slash is not working for me how do I enable it or allow it

Comment: OK, please can you [edit] your question to clarify exactly which parts you understand and have working, and which you don't. Feel free to include multiple attempts, and list how you've tested them, with expected results and actual results. Then we can understand better how to help you understand the general principles involved, rather than just fixing your one example.

Answer (score 1):

`([a-zA-Z0-9-])+` => any alpha numeric combination with hyphen (-)
`/?` => may or may not end with /
that is
`domain.com/name/abcd-efg/21`
or
`domain.com/name/abcd-efg/21/`

The `NC` is important.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^name/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\/?/?$ index.php?var=$1&spell=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Okay thanks but it seems like the forward slash is not working for me instead I used hyphen but I will like to use a forward slash

Comment: Forward slash is not working for me how do I enable it or allow it

Comment: now check it. If it is not working for you, let me know. Because I am using the same in my website